# Selectize.js Diacritics Is Not Working With One Character

Tags: javascript, jquery, diacritics, selectize.js

In my project, `diacritics` option is not working.
For example; I have `İzmir`, but when I type `İ` to the `selectbox`, `İzmir` is not showing on the dropdown. When I type `I`, then `İzmir` is showing.

```
<script>
    var DIACRITICS = {
            'a': '[aÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäå]',
            'c': '[cÇçćĆčČ]',
            'd': '[dđĐďĎ]',
            'e': '[eÈÉÊËèéêëěĚ]',
                    'g': '[gğĞ]',
                    'ı': '[iÌÍÎÏìíîïIİı]',
                    'I': '[iÌÍÎÏìíîïIİı]',
                    'İ': '[iÌÍÎÏìíîïIİı]',
            'i': '[iÌÍÎÏìíîïIİı]',
            'n': '[nÑñňŇ]',
            'o': '[oÒÓÔÕÕÖØòóôõöø]',
            'r': '[rřŘ]',
            's': '[sŠšş]',
            't': '[tťŤ]',
            'u': '[uÙÚÛÜùúûüůŮ]',
            'y': '[yŸÿýÝ]',
            'z': '[zŽž]'
        };
</script>
```

And in the front-end:

```
<script>
$('#select-cikis').selectize({
    create: true,
    sortField: 'text',
    diacritics: true
});
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the server not being able to send all UTF-8 characters in the **.js** correctly.

Some appeared as ? in the page source.

The solution was to use UTF-8 character codes. I found a list with a lot of transliterated characters.

Just replace the DIACRITICS variable in **selectize.js** with this:

```
var DIACRITICS = {
    'A' : '[\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F]',
    'AA' : '[\uA732]',
    'AE' : '[\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2]',
    'AO' : '[\uA734]',
    'AU' : '[\uA736]',
    'AV' : '[\uA738\uA73A]',
    'AY' : '[\uA73C]',
    'B' : '[\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181]',
    'C' : '[\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E]',
    'D' : '[\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779]',
    'DZ' : '[\u01F1\u01C4]',
    'Dz' : '[\u01F2\u01C5]',
    'E' : '[\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E]',
    'F' : '[\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B]',
    'G' : '[\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E]',
    'H' : '[\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D]',
    'I' : '[\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197]',
    'J' : '[\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248]',
    'K' : '[\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2]',
    'L' : '[\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780]',
    'LJ' : '[\u01C7]',
    'Lj' : '[\u01C8]',
    'M' : '[\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C]',
    'N' : '[\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4]',
    'NJ' : '[\u01CA]',
    'Nj' : '[\u01CB]',
    'O' : '[\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C]',
    'OI' : '[\u01A2]',
    'OO' : '[\uA74E]',
    'OU' : '[\u0222]',
    'P' : '[\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754]',
    'Q' : '[\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A]',
    'R' : '[\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782]',
    'S' : '[\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784]',
    'T' : '[\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786]',
    'TZ' : '[\uA728]',
    'U' : '[\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244]',
    'V' : '[\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245]',
    'VY' : '[\uA760]',
    'W' : '[\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72]',
    'X' : '[\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C]',
    'Y' : '[\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE]',
    'Z' : '[\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762]',
    'a' : '[\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250]',
    'aa' : '[\uA733]',
    'ae' : '[\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3]',
    'ao' : '[\uA735]',
    'au' : '[\uA737]',
    'av' : '[\uA739\uA73B]',
    'ay' : '[\uA73D]',
    'b' : '[\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253]',
    'c' : '[\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184]',
    'd' : '[\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A]',
    'dz' : '[\u01F3\u01C6]',
    'e' : '[\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD]',
    'f' : '[\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C]',
    'g' : '[\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F]',
    'h' : '[\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265]',
    'hv' : '[\u0195]',
    'i' : '[\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131]',
    'j' : '[\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249]',
    'k' : '[\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3]',
    'l' : '[\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747]',
    'lj' : '[\u01C9]',
    'm' : '[\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F]',
    'n' : '[\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5]',
    'nj' : '[\u01CC]',
    'o' : '[\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275]',
    'oi' : '[\u01A3]',
    'ou' : '[\u0223]',
    'oo' : '[\uA74F]',
    'p' : '[\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755]',
    'q' : '[\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759]',
    'r' : '[\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783]',
    's' : '[\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u00DF\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B]',
    't' : '[\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787]',
    'tz' : '[\uA729]',
    'u' : '[\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289]',
    'v' : '[\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C]',
    'vy' : '[\uA761]',
    'w' : '[\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73]',
    'x' : '[\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D]',
    'y' : '[\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF]',
    'z': '[\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763]'
};
```

Comment: This solved it for me, however I didn't want to edit the source javascript. Simply setting the encoding on my script tag worked: `<script src='selectize.js' charset='UTF-8'></script>`

Comment: @ChrisHendry Thanks, this worked for me, just save my day. If without charset='UTF-8' in <script> tag, variable DIACRITICS in selectize.js will become Garbled.

Answer (score 0):

There is a weird bug with javascript `String.toLowerCase()` method.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to convert the string to lowercase letters.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "ALİ";
    var res = str.toLowerCase();
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = (res == 'ali');
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = (res == 'ali̇');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can pass that with adding

```
query = query.replace('i̇', 'i');
```

to the `Sifter.prototype.tokenize` method in *selectize.js*

first `i` is different than second `i` they are not same.

code must be look like this;

```
Sifter.prototype.tokenize = function(query) {
    query = trim(String(query || '').toLowerCase());
    query = query.replace('i̇', 'i');
    if (!query || !query.length) return [];
    ...
```

I solved it with this way. Hope that it helps you too.